# How can I disable Java in my browser?

Tags: security, java

[A new Java 0-day exploit was discovered on 2012-08-26](http://blog.fireeye.com/research/2012/08/zero-day-season-is-not-over-yet.html), and [is out in the wild](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/08/27/disable_java_to_block_exploit/). It affects Oracle's Java on Windows, Mac and Linux desktops and affects all major browsers.

Plenty of websites [recommend that users disable Java in the browser](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2012/08/27/disable-java-in-your-browser-to-avoid-a-nasty-new-malware-spreading-attack/). However, I cannot find instructions which cover the most common browsers (Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Firefox, [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29), and [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29)) on Windows and Mac.

How should users disable Java on their system?

I am looking for an easy-to-understand answer which can be understood by friends, family, coworkers and novice computer users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Internet Explorer:

Click on **Tools** (the gear icon at the top right of the browser window), and go to **Manage Add-ons** on the menu.  On the middle of the left-hand side of the window there will be a Show: menu.  Click on **Show** and select **All Add-ons**.  Scroll down on the right to find any Java add-ons.  Right-click and select **Disable** from the menu.

[image: IE Add-ons]

### Firefox on Windows:

You can disable Java by clicking the **Firefox** menu (top left) and go to **Add-ons**.  In the Add-ons panel go to the **Plugins** tab on the left.  Click the **Disable** button on the right of any Java plugins.

[image: Firefox Add-ons]

### Chrome:

Type `chrome://plugins/` in the address bar to reveal the plugins panel.  Find any Java plugins and click the disable button.

### Opera:

Type in `opera:plugins` in the address bar to go to the plugins panel.  Click the Disable link on the right of any Java plugins.